# derivative to variable that depends on other variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Let say   you have a function f that depends on 3 variables: $x,y, t$ and you want to calculate $\dfrac{df(x,y,t)}{dt}$.

In fact you know that $t = c \alpha$  with  $c$ a constant and $\alpha$ a variable.
So in fact, the function $f$ depends on the variables $(x,y,\alpha)$. How can we calculate $\dfrac{df(x,y,t)}{dt}$ ?

I would think we can do: 
$\dfrac{df(x,y,\alpha)}{d\alpha} \dfrac{d\alpha}{dt} = \dfrac{df(x,y,\alpha)}{d\alpha} \left(\dfrac{dt}{d\alpha}\right)^{-1} = \dfrac{df(x,y,\alpha)}{d\alpha} \dfrac{1}{c} $
I doubt if this is correct or not.

thanks in advance

Comment: Yup it seems pretty fine to me.

Comment: Not correct if $x$ or $y$ might depend on $\alpha$.

Comment: @ Open Ball : In my particular case, $x$ and $y$ do not depend on $\alpha$. Do you think it is correct if $x$ and $y$ do not depend on $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.